# ES6 multiple inheritance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Can somebody please explain the meaning of the following valid ES6 code?

```
'use strict';

class first {
    constructor() {
    }
}

class second {
    constructor() {
    }
}

class third extends (first, second) {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

As far as I know, there is no multiple inheritance in JavaScript, but the syntax shown in the example doesn't throw any error (in Node.js 4.3.0), and it works,... - how is what I'm trying to understand, or what does it do there exactly...

Also, I noticed that if I comments out `super()` call, then the code starts throwing error `ReferenceError: this is not defined`.

Comment: @Tushar that question was about Babel, this one is about ES6.

Comment: `(first, second)` is the comma operator, and evaluates to `second`. `first` is thrown away.

Comment: That question is nor related to Babel. Babel is just a tool/library to use ES6 early when browsers are not supporting it.

Comment: @torazaburo if we remove brackets and have just `first, second`, Node.js will reject such code, that's purely Babel syntax.

Comment: Any ES6 processor would reject the code without the parens. As for your original question, just looking at the Babel-generated ES5 code should have made things clear.

Comment: The absence of `super` causing the ReferenceError is entirely unrelated to `(first, second)`. It is the behavior of **any** subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a confusing case of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

```
(1, 2) // 2
(1, 2, 3) // 3
(first, second) // second
```

It doesn't throw an error because it's valid syntax, however it doesn't *work* in the sense that you were expecting either. `third` will only inherit from `second`.

We can verify that this is the case by compiling to ES5 syntax to check that it's not affecting the class definition.

```
var third = (function (_ref) {
  _inherits(third, _ref);

  function third() {
    _classCallCheck(this, third);

    _get(Object.getPrototypeOf(third.prototype), 'constructor', this).call(this);
  }

  return third;
})((first, second));
```

The result of evaluating `(first, second)` is passed in as `_ref`, then `third` `_inherits` from it.

Comment: Are you sure? If we comment out `super()`, then the code starts throwing an error: `ReferenceError: this is not defined`. But it does look like only the `second` one is inherited indeed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. Look at the compiled ES5 version.

Comment: This starts making sense, although this is really confusing, for the way the syntax looks.

Comment: It's no more confusing than any other use of the comma operator.